# Trying to fix ZeroDivisionError in game

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below is in a 60fps pygame.time.Clock loop

```
f = 0
z = 180

while run:
    pygame.time.Clock.tick(60)
        
    f += 1

    if f % z == 0:
        enemy_ship = pygame.Rect(WIDTH-5,randint(0,730),SPACESHIP_WIDTH,SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
        enemy_ships.append(enemy_ship)

        for x in range(random.randint(1,len(enemy_ships))):
            rand_ship = random.choice(enemy_ships)
            enemy_bullet = pygame.Rect(rand_ship.x,rand_ship.y,10,10)
            enemy_bullets.append(enemy_bullet)
            pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('assets','enemy_shoot.wav'))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

    if z > 0:
        z -= 1
        enemy_bullet_vel += 0.2
        #print('{}\n{}'.format(z,enemy_bullet_vel))
```

I'm trying to increase the speed at which the enemy ships spawn, however when z reaches 0, I get a ZeroDivisionError, how would i make it so it still spawns bullets and ships but doesn't give a ZeroDivisionError?

Comment: put a `try`  and a `catch ZeroDivisionError`  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html  or check the value of the denominator before doing the division.

Comment: Exception happens on 181 iteration when `z` eventually becomes `0` and you try to divide `f` to `z` and get remainder in this expression `f % z`.

Comment: `if z == 0 or f % z == 0:` ?